# await does not work as expected in useEffect like componentDidMount in react

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to fire an action and update Redux reducer in React Hook but it does not work like componentDidMount in class component.

In class it works:

```
async componentDidMount () {
  await this.props.fetchCart(this.props.cartItems,this.props.token,this.props.isAuthenticated)
   //it works
   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.ProductsOfCart) );
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
      
      
       ProductsOfCart: state.cartProductsReducer.cartProducts,
      
     }
   }
```

In React hooks, it does not work:

```
useEffect(()=>{
     (async () => {
      await props.fetchCart(props.cartItems,props.token,props.isAuthenticated)
      //ProductOfCart is empty array 
      console.log(JSON.stringify(props.ProductsOfCart))
      
    })();

  },[])
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
      
      
       ProductsOfCart: state.cartProductsReducer.cartProducts,
      
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

below is how you would do it in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {

async function fetchCart() {
await props.fetchCart(props.cartItems,props.token,props.isAuthenticated)
console.log(JSON.stringify(props.ProductsOfCart))
}
fetchCart();

},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "async" like that inside useEffect because async function returns a promise and functions that you call inside useEffect should return nothing. So you should wrap the async function with a function and then call the wrapper.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const fetchData=async () => {
try{
     await props.fetchCart(props.cartItems,props.token,props.isAuthenticated)
   }
catch(e){
     console.log("error in fetching",e)
   }
}

fetchData()
},[])
```

if you get error, you will catch it inside catch block.